# how to access .net webservice classes with php?

Tags: php, .net, web-services

I have a .net `web service` which provide multiple `methods` and `public classes`. 
I want to use these classes in php.
How can I do it?

this is my web service: `http://10.2.3.74/AdaptorRepeater/BillPatientService.asmx?WSDL`

for example I want access to AdmissionVO class and its properties

```
$client = new soapclient('http://10.2.3.74/AdaptorRepeater/BillPatientService.asmx?WSDL');
    $header = new SoapHeader('http://sepas.behdasht.gov.ir/','HeaderMessageVO',$HeaderMessageVO,false);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$send = $client->SavePatientBillSecure($params);
```

I want for example this :

```
$client->AdmissionVO->MedicalRecordNumber = '1234';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SOAP Call You can access any Dot.Net Web service 
You need to have Dot net web service WSDL path
now

```
<?php

 //turn off WSDP caching if not in a production environment
 $ini = ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");

 //instantiate the SOAP client
  $client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/dotnet.asmx?WSDL");
  echo $client->GetAllContactNames()->GetAllContactNamesResult;
   //...optional additional code goes here...
   ?>
```